# libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, aws-lambda, gitlab-ci

I'm running into a weird issue with my GitLab CI/CD pipeline and AWS lambda functions with Python 3.6...

When using an alpine image through GitLab CI/CD, I'm receiving this error on my Lambda. I'm using the Azure Blob Storage SDK to move files from S3 to Azure for a specific purpose.

I'm able to package up my dependencies and everything with WSL on my PC but can't seem to get it to work on my pipeline.

I don't really know what else to add as this seems to be a complicated issue with multiple potential failure points...

Comment: During setup, try to install python3-dev

Comment: I should add, I've added these to my image to no avail... ```apk add --update --no-cache cmd:pip3 gcc musl-dev linux-headers python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev py3-setuptools freeradius-python```